# How to divide the values on the graph axes in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, heatmap

I have ploly Heatmap figure like that:
[image]
I know that y-axis values are measured in GHz (1*10^9 Hz), so I would like to divide all y-axis values by 10^9 so that they look like 4.90 instead of 4.90e+9, for example. How can I do it?

Comment: Try This: `fig.update_layout(yaxis=dict(showexponent='all',exponentformat='none'))`

Comment: @r-beginners I've already tried it and it doesn't seem to work, the exponents stay in place

Comment: I may be able to help if I have the data and code.